# wordpress html formatting issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am facing a very bad issue with my website HTML and CSS .It the html part as you can see that I have used h4 , strong or other things.

```
<h1>The story began.</h1>
<em><strong>This would</strong></em> be an example of a post that I'm trying to reformat via better HTML.

<a href="http://mobiscreenr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/note.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-100" src="http://mobiscreenr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/note.jpg" alt="note" width="119" height="163" /></a>
```

But [this is the end result](http://mobiscreenr.com/test-post-1/).

Comment: here is the code
{{{{

<h1>The story began.</h1>
<em><strong>This would</strong></em> be an example of a post that I'm trying to reformat via better HTML.

<a href="http://mobiscreenr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/note.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-100" src="http://mobiscreenr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/note.jpg" alt="note" width="119" height="163" /></a>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments...It's unreadable. Also...what's your question? What's the expected output? The page is rendering correctly according to your defined CSS styles.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: http://mobiscreenr.com/test-post-1/

See this link its the current output and i want it in better HTML.

Comment: Then add some CSS styles...

Comment: On the visual part of Post its working but its not working on Website.

Comment: please provide the screenshot of how it looks in the visual editor.

Comment: please also note that whenever you create or edit any page or post in a wordpress website, it will always look different in frontend as compared to visual-editor, it is because at frontend style code ( CSS stylesheets) added to the post or page.

Comment: Its working normaly As if you use <h4>Hi</h4>   then it will become large like Heading 4 size in html ...


But when i post it then it does not works on website and it comes in normal text size.

Comment: See this link its the end result http://mobiscreenr.com/test-post-1/ but i want {The story began.} to be in h4 as i did in my html side.

Comment: So you need to change your CSS, what you're seeing in the Wordpress editor is just the browsers default styles, your site styling is not being applied here. So you need to add in some rules to your CSS about the h4 sizing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme's style.css file and find on line 10 the following css:

```
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var, optgroup {
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
```

after this line add:

```
em {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

&

```
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

p.s. you can edit css files through WordPress by going to 'Appearance' / 'Editor' and finding the style.css file.